# Lost 10 reputation only on iOS app, not on website

Tags: bug, reputation, mobile-web, ios-app

This really weird thing happened today. I opened the Stack Exchange iOS App only to find that I got + 10 reputation and the immediately lost it again as it says -10 reputation. I thought that this may be due to my answer being down voted, but when I checked it said a down vote is -2. To make things weirder, when I checked the score on the answer, it says nothing was voted down.

[image: vote count]

Now on my Laptop, I logged in to SO just to find two up votes and no sign whatsoever of the 10 reputation loss. Anyone got an idea what happened?

When I refresh the iOS app's table view, the + and - 10 change up and down from position one to two.

This is a screenshot from the iOS App:
[image]

Comment: Weird.  I guess someone reversed their upvote, and the iOS app did some weird caching right when your post had 3 upvotes.  And then re-notified you when one was retracted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either someone reversed their upvote, or the upvoter was banned/deleted.  Those are the only two ways you can lose 10 points in one shot.  That would also explain why you lost 10 points without a trace of what happened.

Comment: Banned? I think you mean suspended, but that doesn't remove votes. Nor do all account-deletions...

Comment: If a user is banned (not suspended, but removed from the community) it will reverse all of that user's votes.

Comment: Ah, you mean destroyed. Which is one of the varieties of deleted...

Comment: Yeah.  Didn't have the proper semantics, but that's what I meant.  :o)